# Dynamic UITableViewCell with UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have an array of HTML strings, some of them are with photos, some of them long, some short, some with links - they are all different.

Now I have a `UITableView` and I want to display those HTML strings on the table, each string in each cell by it's index. My problem is that I don't know the height of each cell, I need to calculate the height by the height of each HTML string, but I can only know it after the `UIWebView` is loaded.

I need a suggestion for a good solution to this issue, something that will looks good. I've already tried to use `UIWebViewDelegate` to change the cell frame after loading the HTML string into the WebView but it looks bad.. and messes the table view completely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can refer to this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resort to animation when adding the cells.

Add the cells one by one (1 indexPath at a time) in your `UITableView` (**and** datasource), by doing this:

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                          // or UITableViewRowAnimationNone
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Your `UITableView` will slowly grow with an animation as the data becomes available.

If you need to resize an **existing** cell, delete it and immediately re-insert it, all within a single beginUpdates/endUpdates sequence:

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I accepted your answer while understanding that there is no 'smooth' solution to this question. There is no way to add `UIWebView` in `UITableViewCell` that's gonna work smooth and clean.

Comment: Don't give up! If the size of a `UITableViewCell` changes after the fact (*say you started with 10 pix tall and now you need 20*) you can actually use the method I described above: **(1)** beginUpdates to freeze the UI **(2)** delete and re-insert right away the very row you are resizing ( `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` + `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`) **(3)** endUpdates to release the UI. This will be smooth.

Comment: Yeah i've used it before, I can just reload the cell I want. But it's not good to me, because I want the table to load smoothly and this is massy... But thanks anyway! I don't have 1-3 cells, I have 50-60 cells...

Comment: One possibly cool way to do this is use animation scheduling: make a queue of animations where the `^{completion}` method of one triggers the next one. If you schedule each animation within 1/15th secs of each other, you could load your table withing about 4 seconds, slowly growing. Note that at worse the user can only see a dozen cells on the screen at once, so once you are past the visible part, animation is possibly of little value